# How to encapsulate Java Streams operations

Tags: java, java-stream

One of the drawbacks which I see when using the Java `Stream` API is that the code seems less readable when compared to its iterative version.

By the way, that is what I think, but I am just giving some context (to avoid [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), what I am going to ask is independent of that, so hopefully this will **not** be considered an *opinion based* question.

Encapsulation usually increases code readability (again, just given context) so I am looking for the best way to encapsulate Java `Stream` operations.

For example, this is a simple series of `Stream` operations implemented the typical way (no encapsulation):

```
    void method1() {
        List<Integer> result = IntStream.range(1, 10)

                // Two Stream "intermediate" operations:
                .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0).map(i -> i * 2)

                .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

        log.debug("Result: {}", result);
        // Result: [2, 6, 10, 14, 18]
    }
```

And this is my first and simple attempt to achieve encapsulation, by adding the `filterOutEvenNumbersAndMultiplyByTwo` method:

```
    IntStream filterOutEvenNumbersAndMultiplyByTwo(IntStream stream) {
        return stream.filter(i -> i % 2 != 0).map(i -> i * 2);
    }

    void method2() {
        List<Integer> result = filterOutEvenNumbersAndMultiplyByTwo(IntStream.range(1, 10))
                .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

        log.debug("Result: {}", result);
        // Result: [2, 6, 10, 14, 18]
    }
```

As you can see I have encapsulated two intermediate `Stream` operations inside a new method, which does not seem to make much sense in this case but it is just an example, there could be more than two `Stream` operations and also more complicated ones.

The new method increases readability (IMHO) and can be unit tested (that's a fact).
The code above works, but it does not look very nice or clean, ideally, I would like to be able to write something such as:

```
        List<Integer> result = IntStream.range(1, 10)

                // This obviously does not compile
                .filterOutEvenNumbersAndMultiplyByTwo()

                .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I guess that it could be done but it would require significant effort since I would have to implement the `Stream` interface...

Is there another way?
Maybe a library exists which I could use?
Maybe my OO mind is trying to force encapsulation on something that's not meant to but I still wonder if it is possible.

Comment: maybe creating a method that generates the filter would help

Comment: "One of the drawbacks which I see when using the Java Stream API is that the code seems less readable when compared to its iterative version." maybe for simple tasks but even then it's debatable. the more complex the computation the less readable it gets via iterative approach IMO.  btw I'd use `mapToObj` rather than `map`+ `boxed` i.e. `IntStream.range(1, 10) .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0) .mapToObj(i -> i * 2) .collect(Collectors.toList());` . such a simple task reads well to me hence wouldn't try to encapsulate anything.

Comment: IMO `filterOutEvenNumbersAndMultiplyByTwo` is really a long name and doesn't improves code readability. And it's a known fact that "Stream API" isn't the go to approach always, especially for small task.

Comment: further to my comment, as an example.... do you think it's more readable to perform a grouping operation purely with imperative approach rather than `source.stream().collect(groupingBy(...))` ? surely not. this post is opinion based and the example given isn't a good one to attempt to refactor.

Comment: I totally and respectfully disagree: my question is not _opinion_ _based_, I was just trying to provide context to the question, in order to void the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).
Independently of my motivation to ask the question, the reality is that I asked a very specific question: whether it is possible to achieve something in a better way than the way I came up with.
And by the way, I am fully aware of the fact that my example is simple, that was my intention and I mentioned it myself, it was for the sake of getting my point across.

Answer (score 2):

`filterOutEvenNumbers` is simply a predicate.
`multiplyByTwo` is a map operation.

```
// we can unit test these
IntPredicate filterOutEvenNumbers = i -> i % 2 != 0
IntUnaryOperator multiplyByTwo = i -> i * 2;
```

You can have N number of Predicates / map operations.
We can also switch various predicates / map operations here.

```
IntStream.range(1, 10)
    .filter(filterOutEvenNumbers)
    .map(multiplyByTwo)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks, that's useful information but it does not really answer my question. I am looking for a way to encapsulate and unit test
`.filter(filterOutEvenNumbers).map(multiplyByTwo)` as **a whole**.
A way which is better than the way I have explained in my question, if any exists.